# How to retrieve data from array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program for a hotel booking system. I currently have the room info in an array and I wish the customer to enter the ID of the room and it will retrieve all the details for that certain room. Here is the code for the array:

```
  Room [] rooms = 
  {
    new Room("GARDEN0001", "NorthWest Garden View", 45.00),
    new Room("GARDEN0002", "SouthEast Garden View", 65.0),
    new Room("GARDEN0003", "North Garden View", 35.00),
    new Room("GARDEN0004", "South Garden View", 52.0),
    new Room("GARDEN0005", "West Garden View", 35.00),
    new Room("GARDEN0006", "East Garden View", 35.00)      
  };
```

The format is ID, Description, Price.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you may better use a Map instead of an array and map your id with the Room object. Otherwise just iterate array and check Id for each object to match.

Comment: Just use the `[]` operator? Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @Mureinik index of array is not same as the id of the object

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate the array with a for-each loop, and check if it matches:

```
for (Room r : rooms) { 
    if (r.id.equals(REQUESTED_ID)) {
           //do something with it
    }
}
```

However, if your array grows large, you might want to switch to a smarter data structure such as a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), that allows smart (and quick) searches.

Note you will also need to override `Room#equals()` and `Room#hashCode()` in order to use a `HashSet`, or similarly a [`HashMap<String,Room>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: IMHO not a good solution - array and set are the wrong data structures for the problem. Map is much more suitable.

Comment: @Lrrr Really disagree, considering `Room` should be an immutable object.

Answer (score 1):

You can access/retrieve the items of an array by it's `indexes`.

**Let's say :**

```
int[] x = new int[5];
x[2] = 4; // Access the 3rd element
```

The first element's index always starts from `0`, and it's called `base index`.

So if the size of the array is 3, then all the element's indexes are 0,1,2.

In this case, you can access the items :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < rooms.length ; i ++) {
    if(room.getID().equals(userInput)){
    //
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
for(Room room : rooms) {
   // access by room. , here room is you item
   if(room.getID().equals(userInput)){
    //
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can do as in [amit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572670/amit)'s answer, and iterate through them, I strongly suggest you to use some form of Map. That is what they are made for.

```
Map<String, Room> rooms = new HashMap<>();
Room r = new Room("GARDEN0001", "NorthWest Garden View", 45.00);
rooms.put(r.getId(), r);
r = new Room("GARDEN0002", "SouthEast Garden View", 65.0);
rooms.put(r.getId(), r);
r = new Room("GARDEN0003", "North Garden View", 35.00);
rooms.put(r.getId(), r);
r = new Room("GARDEN0004", "South Garden View", 52.0);
rooms.put(r.getId(), r);
r = new Room("GARDEN0005", "West Garden View", 35.00);
rooms.put(r.getId(), r);
r = new Room("GARDEN0006", "East Garden View", 35.00);
rooms.put(r.getId(), r);
```

(I'm assuming your `Room` class has a `getId()` method that returns the id.)
You can then retrieve rooms as this:

```
Room room = rooms.get("GARDENOOO2");
```

or

```
Room room = rooms.get(savedId);
```

Comment: why store the id as the Map key and in the Room itself?

Comment: Only because I assume he has made the Room class already and uses the id for other things as well.

Comment: How can I create a getId() method?

Comment: I assume, from how your `Room` constructor works that you have a field `private String id`  or similar in your `Room` class. Add a getter to that like this:
`public String getId()
{ return id }`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java8, you can do it this way:

```
Arrays.stream(rooms).filter(room -> "YOUR_ID".equals(room.getId())).findFirst().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code just to give you idea.

```
for(Room room:rooms ){
if(room.getID().equals(userInput)){
 return room;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are accessed by index. There is no way to directly get the `Room` by `ID`.
You could loop through the `rooms` and select the correct `Room` as follows:

```
private Room getRoomById(String id) {
    for (Object room : rooms) {
        if (room.getId == id) {
            return room;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `(Object room:rooms)` -> `getId` won't compile very well, `room.getId == id` -> should be `equals()`...

Answer (score 0):

Array is the wrong tool for the job. What you have done is give yourself a harder problem than you needed to. I would recommend using a TreeMap to store unique room ids as key (Java String have correct implementations of equals, hashcode and compareTo methods), and refactored Room instances as values.

Change your Room value object by removing the key field then store it as the TreeMap value, using the room id (in a Java String) as the TreeMap key.

By employing a TreeMap theres no need to loop through the stored rooms, you can use the TreeMaps get(Object key) method to retrieve the required room details.